# Empty body when using Micronaut controller

Tags: micronaut

I have a controller which looks like this which I am using during testing to check the endpoint was called with the correct params:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post

@CompileStatic
@Controller("/appurl")
class AppController {

    AppParams lastRequestParams

    AppResponse nextResponse = new AppResponse('xxx')

    @Post
    AppResponse generateAccessToken(
        @Header("TraceId") String traceId,
        @Body AppRequest appRequest) {

        this.lastRequestParams = new AppParams(appRequest, traceId)
        return nextResponse
    }
}
```

However, the response is always throwing an 'empty body' error.  If I set a breakpoint, I can definitely see that this code is being called.  Any ideas?

I have tried changing the code to return Rx classes instead and I get the same error.

Comment: Show the code for `AppResponse`

Comment: As you say turned out to be AppResponse which couldn't be created by Jackson.

Comment: @J.Snook have you found the answer?